# How to combine all CSV 'S to one CSV in an order

Tags: linux, awk, sed, csv

I have a bunch of csv 's in folder.I want to combine them in an order.

I have the csv files as

```
state_1_result_6.csv,
state_1_result_8.csv,
state_1_result_10.csv,
state_1_result_12.csv.....
```

Each of the csv has one line without no header, so the content of a `state_i_result.csv` will be like:

```
1,2,3,69,19,1,2,6,10,12,30,28
```

I want to combine in such a order that first line will be state_1_result_6.csv and second line will be state_1_result_8.csv and so on.

I tried with

```
cat state*.csv > final.csv
```

But it is not merging in a order.

Comment: is there any pattern on the `i`s from `state_i_result.csv`? Every 2 starting from 6? So we can build a loop to generate them.

Comment: I edited the question now.The i are same in state_i_result_j.csv.The j has a pattern 6,8,10,12 only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know them, just loop through the list of indexes:

```
for i in 6 8 10 12;
do
   cat state_1_result_${i}.csv >> final.csv
done
```

You can also use a C-loop:

```
for ((i=6; i<=12; i+=2))
```

Comment: I am new to linux so how can I execute the first loop.I know I cannot directly type that in the command line.Could u please tell how to execute the for loop?

Comment: @John yes, you can type this in the command line. Just type the lines and when you find a new line, just type Enter!

Comment: Thank u I could not upvote because no enough reputations.Anyway thanks again

Comment: @John glad that it worked to you :)

Answer (score 0):

It is good to see that the indices are just before the file extension.

```
cat state*.csv > final.csv
```

considers the sorting by ascii characters. That is, { 6, 8, 10, 12 } on sorting becomes { 10, 12 , 6, 8 }.

In the manual page of *ls*, there is an option -v, that sorts according to the version number, that is what is required. Therefore, you may use

```
cat `ls -v | grep .csv` > final.csv
```

if those are the only csv files in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

or more simply

```
ls -v *.csv | xargs cat >> final.csv
```

-v order by version number